# Use of unnasigned local variable

Tags: c#

I just written this code and got an error from it. After a few minutes of googling I can't seem to find the answer. Here is my code:

```
using System;

namespace tugas1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Title = "Layanan Pet Hotel / Pet Grooming";

            int kategoriHewan, ukuranHewan, layananHewan, layananPetHotel;
            string jumlahHewan, namaLayananPetHotel;
            double harga = 0;

            Console.WriteLine("==============================================");
            Console.WriteLine("Tolong masukkan kategori: ");
            Console.WriteLine("[1] Dog");
            Console.WriteLine("[2] Cat");
            Console.WriteLine("==============================================");
            Console.Write("Masukkan kategori hewan [1/2]: ");
            kategoriHewan = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            if (kategoriHewan == 1)
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("==============================================");
                Console.WriteLine("Tolong masukkan ukuran: ");
                Console.WriteLine("[1] Besar");
                Console.WriteLine("[2] Sedang");
                Console.WriteLine("[3] Kecil");
                Console.WriteLine("==============================================");
                Console.Write("Masukkan ukuran: [1/2/3]");
                ukuranHewan = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            }
            else if (kategoriHewan == 2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Untuk kategori Cat tidak memiliki ukuran.");
            }
            Console.Clear();
            Console.Write("Masukkan jumlah hewan: ");
            jumlahHewan = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("==============================================");
            Console.WriteLine("Tolong masukkan kategori layanan: ");
            Console.WriteLine("[1] Layanan Pet Hotel");
            Console.WriteLine("[2] Layanan Pet Grooming");
            Console.WriteLine("==============================================");
            Console.Write("Masukkan kategori hewan [1/2]: ");
            layananHewan = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            if (kategoriHewan == 1)
            {
                if (layananHewan == 1)
                {
                    if (ukuranHewan == 1)
                    {
                        Console.Clear();
                        Console.WriteLine("==============================================");
                        Console.WriteLine("[1] Suite Room + Meal             (Rp. 110.000,-)");
                        Console.WriteLine("[2] Suite Room + No Meal          (Rp. 105.000,-)");
                        Console.WriteLine("[3] Standard Room + Meal          (Rp. 100.000,-)");
                        Console.WriteLine("[4] Standard Room + No Meal       (Rp.  95.000,-)");
                        Console.WriteLine("==============================================");
                        Console.Write("Masukkan Layanan Pet Hotel untuk kategori Dog [1/2/3/4]: ");
                        layananPetHotel = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                        switch (layananPetHotel)
                        {
                            case 1:
                                harga = 110000;
                                namaLayananPetHotel = "Suite Room + Meal";
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                harga = 105000;
                                namaLayananPetHotel = "Suite Room + No Meal";
                                break;
                            case 3:
                                harga = 100000;
                                namaLayananPetHotel = "Standard Room + Meal";
                                break;
                            case 4:
                                harga = 95000;
                                namaLayananPetHotel = "Standard Room + No Meal";
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

I got these error:

Use of unassigned local variable 'ukuranHewan'
The variable 'namaLayananPetHotel' is assigned but its value is never used
The variable 'harga' is assigned but its value is never used

Comment: Welcome to SO.  ```ukuranHewan``` is defined only if ```kategoriHewan == 1```, otherwise it isn't defined.   As for the other two,  you define those variables but you don't use them.

Comment: give a default value when declare it. for example, `int  ukuranHewan = 0;`

Comment: Further to @ewong comment, the error arises because you refer later in ukuranHewan in an `if`. The compiler complains, because it cannot be sure at runtime, where it will have a value at this point.

Comment: "...value is never used" isn't normally an *error* by the way, Otis just a warning indicator that you might have forgotten to write some code or might have forgotten to remove some code

Comment: thanks everyone! now i'm left with the warning which is 'namaLayananPetHotel' and 'harga' which confuses me a lil bit

Answer (score 0):

Analysis

The reason why "ukuranHewan" is showing unassigned because

```
if (kategoriHewan == 1)
```

if the above condition is false, the value for ukuranHewan is not assigned.

```
if (ukuranHewan == 1)
```

but here you are using irrespective of the value is assigned or not.

*"namaLayananPetHotel" is assigned but never used. because in the switch statement you are assigning the value but you are not displaying anywhere ,same reason for harga also.*